# Dados não estão sendo inserido no banco

Tags: php, html

estou desenvolvendo um formulário para enviar algumas informações para um banco.

Testei a conexão com o banco pelo php e está conectando certinho.

Porém os dados não estão sendo inseridos na tabela, estou verificando a alguns dias mas não encontro onde possa estar o erro.

Ps. Sou iniciante em programção, por isso talvez esteja me equivocando em algo simples, desde já agradeço se alguém puder me auxiliar.

Segue os códigos:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ptbr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="titulo">
        <h1>Personal control</h1>
    </header>

    <div>
        <a href="index.html">Cadastro</a>
        <a href="search.html">Pesquisa</a>
    </div>

    <main class="box">
        <form class="formulario" name="form" action="processa.php" method="post">
            <label for="nomeproduto">Nome do produto</label>
            <input type="text" id="nomeproduto" name="nome" required maxlength="30">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Categoria do produto</legend>
                <select name="categoria">
                    <option value="none">-none-</option>
                    <option value="bebidas">Bebidas</option>
                    <option value="comida">Comida</option>
                    <option value="doces">Doces</option>
                    <option value="roupas">Roupas</option>
                    <option value="eletronicos">Eletronicos</option>
                    <option value="combustivel">Combustível</option>
                    <option value="moradia">Moradia</option>
                    <option value="planos_e_digitais">Planos e digitais</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <label for="datacompra">Data da compra</label>
            <input type="date" id="data_compra" required>

            <label for="precocompra">Valor da compra</label>
            <input type="number" id="precocompra" name="valor_compra" required placeholder="Ex: 15,00" step="0.01" min="0">

            <fieldset>
                <p>Prioridade</p>

                <label for="alta">Alta</label>
                <input type="radio" name="prioridade" value="A" id="alta" checked>

                <label for="normal">Normal</label>
                <input type="radio" name="prioridade" value="N" id="normal">

                <label for="baixa">Baixa</label>
                <input type="radio" name="prioridade" value="B" id="baixa">

                <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Cadastrar produto" class="enviar">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </main>

    <footer>
    <p>© 2020 Copyright Personal control - Desenvolvido por Rafael Lander</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$database = "personal_control";
$username = "user";
$password = "senha";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$data_compra = $_POST['data_compra'];
$valor_compra = $_POST['valor_compra'];
$prioridade = $_POST['prioridade'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos(NOME, CATEGORIA, DATA_COMPRA, VALOR_COMPRA, PRIORIDADE) VALUES ('$nome','$categoria','$data_compra','$valor_compra','$prioridade')";

mysqli_query($sql, $conn);

if (mysqli_query($sql, $conn)) {
      echo "Produto cadastrado com sucesso";
      echo "<a href='index.html'>Clique aqui para realizar um novo cadastro</a><br>";
      echo "<a href='search.html'>Clique aqui para realizar uma consulta</a><br>";  
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Você colocou a query em uma variável, mas não a executou. Utilize mysqli_query($sql);

Comment: @WallaceMagalhães não rolou, ele completa o fluxo dizendo que o produto foi cadastrado com sucesso, mas quando consulto o banco nada foi inserido :\

Comment: Editei o codigo php aqui, do jeito que está aqui no meu ambiente, acredito que pelas instruções que me foram passadas aqui deveria estar funcionando depois da correção.

Comment: Opa, boa noite... Não consegui identificar o seu erro, mas uma coisa que notei é que o seu código necessita escapar as strings que serão inseridas no banco de dados... utilize 

$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dado']); E outra: evite expor o código sql na mensagem de erro, apenas informe que houve um erro ao inserir, não precisa expor o seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você abriu a conexão definiu a query($sql) mas não executou, segue um exemplo:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

olha o trecho específico que executa sua query: $conn->query($sql)

editei seu código no meu ambiente, observei que olocal e funcionou perfeitamente, exceto que você estava invertendo as variáveis na função, o correto: mysqli_query($conn, $sql), e essa mesma linha estava sendo repetida.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "myblog";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$data_compra = $_POST['data_compra'];
$valor_compra = $_POST['valor_compra'];
$prioridade = $_POST['prioridade'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos(NOME, CATEGORIA, DATA_COMPRA, VALOR_COMPRA, 
PRIORIDADE)VALUES('.$nome.','.$categoria.','.$data_compra.',
'.$valor_compra.',
'.$prioridade.')";


  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Produto cadastrado com sucesso";
  echo "<a href='index.html'>Clique aqui para realizar um novo cadastro</a> 
   <br>";
    echo "<a href='search.html'>Clique aqui para realizar uma consulta</a> 
  <br>";  
  }else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
   }


     mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Sim, essa parte de executar eu vi que eu não tinha colocado mesmo, mas por exemplo depois de atribuir a consulta à variável $sql na linha de baixo eu adicionei `mysqli_query($sql);`
Mesmo assim os dados não estão sendo inseridos.

Comment: Marcos, ele está retornando : `Error: INSERT INTO produtos(NOME, CATEGORIA, DATA_COMPRA, VALOR_COMPRA, PRIORIDADE) VALUES ('','','','','')`
Mas ainda não entendi o pq ?

Comment: tenta assim: $sql = 'INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES (".$nome.", ".$sobrenome.", ".$email.")';

Comment: Olá Marcos, `$sql = "INSERT INTO produtos(NOME, CATEGORIA, DATA_COMPRA, VALOR_COMPRA, PRIORIDADE) VALUES (".$nome.",".$categoria.",".$data_compra.",".$valor_compra.",".$prioridade.")";` alterei conforme você me recomendou, mas ainda sim ele não está inserindo :\

Comment: Bom... no else onde coloquei está linha: `echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($sql);` para que ele me mostrasse o erro, ele está retornando a linha da query do insert: `Error: INSERT INTO produtos(NOME, CATEGORIA, DATA_COMPRA, VALOR_COMPRA, PRIORIDADE) VALUES (".$nome.",".$categoria.",".$data_compra.",".$valor_compra.",".$prioridade.")`

Comment: Sim, exatamente como você recomendou !

Comment: observe que eu editei a resposta com os seus dados e funcionou, você estava invertendo as variáveis mysqli_query($sql, $conn); o correto é mysqli_query($conn, $sql); e tava inserindo duas vezes a mesma função

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, as variáveis estavam invertidas.
Muito obrigado Marcos, vc não sabe o quanto me ajudou, valeu.